# Reload data for jqGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid in a master detail mode. When I click on a row in the master grid I run the SelectedRowHandler javascript function which I want to update the details grid but its not working.

The selected row handler is called and the call to the action is called but the grid does not update.

Here is the js

```
    function SelectedRowHandler(rowId) {
        var rowData = this.p.data[this.p._index[rowId]];           

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '/Invoice/invoiceitems2',
            data: { invoiceId: rowData.Id },
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                $("#InvoiceItemsGrid").jqGrid("GridUnload");                    
                var mygrid = $("#InvoiceItemsGrid")[0];
                var myjsongrid = eval("(" + data.responseText + ")");
                myjsongrid = null;
                data = null;
            },
            viewrecords: true                
        });

        return true;
    }
```

The ActionResult is

```
    [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    public ActionResult InvoiceItems2(int invoiceId)
    {
        var response = new JqGridResponse();

        var invoiceItems = _invoiceItemRepository.GetMany(p => p.InvoiceId == invoiceId);
        foreach (var x in invoiceItems)
        {

            response.Records.Add(new JqGridRecord(Convert.ToString(x.InvoiceItemId), new InvoiceItemViewModel()
                                                                                         {
                                                                                             Id = x.InvoiceItemId,
                                                                                             PartNo = x.PartNo,
                                                                                             Description =
                                                                                                 x.Description,
                                                                                             Quantity = x.Quantity,
                                                                                             Price = x.Price,
                                                                                             Total =
                                                                                                 x.Quantity*x.Price
                                                                                         }));

        }


        return new JqGridJsonResult() {Data = response};


    }
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you are not loading grid, just making an ajax call.
2. Why are you getting the rowdata using rowid and again using rowdata getting rowid ?

Try this instead of your ajax call

```
jQuery("#your_detail_grid_id").jqGrid('setGridParam',{url:"/Invoice/invoiceitems2?invoiceId="+rowId,page:1}).trigger('reloadGrid');
```

See the Master Detail in [jqgrid demo](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

Advanced -> Master Detail

Comment: Thank you. It does not work because it is not making the http request to invoice/invoiceitems2 but I am sure it should so I will look further.
I am using Lib.Web.Mvc and the selectedrowhander only passes the rowId which is in the range 1 to 10 (say if there are 10 rows per page) I need the invoiceId to get the corresponding invoiceItems from the selected Invoice. Its not implemented yet but the rowId is an integer and the rowData.Id is a GUID.